# MySQL - Return rows only if all the values in WHERE clause are present

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database that stores exam records: `tbl_exams` stores the id and name of exams - there are only 9 exams and so only 9 records in this table as the exams are fixed and do not change. `tbl_exam_details` stores all the details for an exam entry, and includes the corresponding id from `tbl_exams` - there is a foreign key constraint for this. What I'm trying to do is create a query that returns rows only if all 9 exams have been taken by a certain student and the `pass_or_fail` field is '1' - I use `tinyint(1)` to store 1 which is pass, or 0 which is fail). This is essentially to check if all 9 exams have been passed.

This is what I have so far, however it is returning rows even when the student has only completed one or two exams:

```
SELECT tbl_exam_details.student_id, exam_name, exam_date, pass_or_fail FROM tbl_exam_details
INNER JOIN tbl_exams ON tbl_exams.exam_id = tbl_exam_details.exam_id
WHERE student_id = 1 AND pass_or_fail = 1
AND tbl_exam_details.exam_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
ORDER BY exam_details_id
```

What I need is for the query to only return rows once all 9 exams have been passed. So, if a student has passed 8 exams, the query should return 0 rows. If anyone could help me out it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide sample data and desired results?

Comment: You could create a `all_exams` column that would be automatically updated when the table is modified. all_exams = 1 if all of the exam_id  are set, 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ted.student_id, 
       exam_name, 
       exam_date, 
       pass_or_fail 
FROM tbl_exam_details ted
INNER JOIN tbl_exams 
   ON tbl_exams.exam_id = ted.exam_id
WHERE student_id = 1
  AND (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM tbl_exam_details ted2
       WHERE ted2.pass_or_fail = 1
         AND ted2.student_id = ted.student_id
      ) = 9  -- mean this student pass 9 exams
ORDER BY exam_details_id
```

Comment: Why not `WHERE tbl_exam_details.pass_or_fail = 1 AND  tbl_exam_details.student_id = ted.student_id`?

Comment: @JohnHC Yes I was fixing that. Thanks

Comment: Marking this as correct as it also displays the extra fields I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT ed.student_id
FROM tbl_exam_details ed
WHERE ed.student_id = 1 AND ed.pass_or_fail = 1 AND
      ed.exam_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
GROUP BY ed.student_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 9;  -- or maybe COUNT(DISTINCT exam_id) = 9
```

This returns the student ids that have passed the 9 exams.  It doesn't include any other information.

Comment: This is exactly it, thank you! Will accept as correct when it lets me. What did you meant by "or maybe COUNT(DISTINCT exam_id) = 9" just out of curiosity?

Comment: @sinesine In case one exam can appear `passed` multiple times. But in this case you can only pass the exam one time, so shouldnt be a problem.

Comment: btw you dont need `and ed.exam_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)` you already say there is only 9 exams, and you want all 9. so the `count(*) = 9` take care of that

Answer (score 0):

You can group_concat for a full list...

```
select x1.*
from 
(
select t1.*, group_concat(distinct exam_id order by exam_id separator '|') as x_list
from tbl_exam_details t1
where pass_or_fail = 1
group by student_id
) x1
where x_list = '1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9'
```

Comment: You probably need add order by on the `concat`?

Comment: This produces an error: `#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias`